# applying derivatives of periodic functions

Tags: derivatives

A railway 'bumper' spring is ttached to a fixed barrier at the end of a shunting track. The spring is compressed a distance of 1.5cm when a carriage runs into the bumper and first returns to its starting position after 0.2seconds. Find the maximum speed with which the bumper moves outwards.

my solution:

movement of the bumper: 
x=1.5sin5πt

speed of the bumper: 
v=7.5πcos5πt

amplitude is 7.5π so the answer calculated is 23.56, but apparently the correct answer is half of 23.56 which is 11.78cm/s Why?

Comment: What should be the time period of the wave?

Comment: oh is it 0.2 which will end up 11.78 right